# How to find the address of a string using a char pointer

Tags: c++, string

Consider the following example

I want to print the address of `"hello"`, not of `ptr`

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

char *ptr = "HELLO";

cout<<"VALUE OF ptr"<<ptr;

cout<<"ADDRESS OF ptr"<<&ptr;

cout<<"WANT TO PRINT ADDRESS OF STRING HELLO";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? What's the difference between address of HELLO and address of ptr?

Comment: Do you always shout?

Comment: I don't think the question is unclear. The OP wants to print the address of the string, not the address of the pointer object. The ALL-CAPS (which I've edited) was unnecessary, but it didn't make the question unclear.

Answer (score 3):

The `<<` operator for most types prints the *value* of the right operand. The `<<` operator for `char*` is different in that it prints the string that the `char*` value points to; it dereferences the pointer, and then traverses the characters of the string, printing each one, until it reaches the terminating `'\0'` null character.

To print the pointer value rather than what it points to, just convert it to `void*`, since `<<` for `void*` prints the actual pointer value:

```
cout << "The address of the string is " << (void*)ptr << "\n";
```

or, if you prefer:

```
cout << "The address of the string is " << static_cast<void*>(ptr) << "\n";
```

(Incidentally, `ptr` should be a `const char*` rather than a `char*`.

Answer (score 2):

Cast it to any other pointer.  (void*)ptr or reinterpret_cast<int*>(ptr) or something.